# Solr log: Multiple values encountered for non multiValued field _basetemplates_s

Tags: solr, configuration, indexing

I'm on Solr 4.10.4, Sitecore 8.1 160519.

The configuration of the custom index is

```
<field fieldName="_basetemplates" returnType="string" multiValued="true" storageType="yes" indexType="untokenized">
           Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.AllTemplates, Sitecore.ContentSearch
</field>
```

The error message I receive is

```
multiple values encountered for non multiValued field _basetemplates_s:
[c6576836910c4a3dba03c277dbd3b827, 1930bbeb7805471aa3be4858ac7cf696]
```

Considering that the field clearly has the *multiValued* attribute set to true, I'm puzzled as to why I am receiving this error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have the change the `returnType`. That is now string, which is not multiValued.. change that to `stringCollection`. Keep the multiValued as well (although I'm not sure it is even needed) - but I'm quite sure the returnType needs to indicate the multivalue (too).

The fact that your error mentioned a `_s` suffix indicates that a single value should be expected - after changing this it should become a `_sm` suffix.

Comment: Thank you, I will try. What's the difference between "stringCollection" and "text"?

Comment: As far as I know there are 2 differences: first is the "Collection" which indicates multiple strings instead of 1. Second is string vs text, where string is used for small non-tokenized and non-analyzed values.